# NewDirectory with new empty file

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory

> Blockquote

The new_directory function creates a new directory inside the current working directory, then creates a new empty file inside the new directory, and returns the list of files in that directory. Complete the function to create a file "script.py" in the directory "PythonPrograms".

```
import os

def new_directory(directory, filename):
  #Before creating a new directory, check to see if it already exists
   for filename in os.listdir(directory):
      if  os.path.isdir(directory):
          os.mkdir(os.path.join(directory,filename))



   return os.listdir(os.path.join(directory,filename))
  # Create the new file inside of the new directory

  # Return the list of files in the new directory
 print(new_directory("PythonPrograms", "script.py"))


 output should be:
 ['script.py']
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @larsks my output is with bunch of file,not that empty file that i've created

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code, it worked fine for me.
First it checks if the directory already exists or not, and then creates the file, and list the directory.

```
import os

def createDir(dirname, filename):
    filepath = os.path.join(dirname, filename)
    if not os.path.exists(dirname):
        os.makedirs(dirname)
        f = open(filepath, "a")
        f.close()
        print("Directory and File created Successfully")
        print(os.listdir(dirname))
    else:
        print("Directory Already Exist")

createDir("PythonPrograms", "script.py")
```

Comment: did you get the problem statement,it is a web based question,output should be ['script.py'] the file will be new,directory will be new,i tried your code before by printing one by one is good idea,still we should return output with new directory with file 'script.py'

Comment: Well, as per original question, this is what it says, creates a new directory inside the current working directory, then creates a new empty file inside the new directory, and returns the list of files in that directory. so in that directory means the new directory as per the question, and that directory has the new file that was created. what output do you get from the code that I had shared, and what were you expecting, may be you rephrase the question to make it more clear.

Comment: hi @Shibu tewar, my question is it should return ['script.py'],its not printing the same,its a silly bug,but still i can't find the solution,would you like to help??

Comment: Hi @rakesh.data I ran the code again, I get the output `Directory and File created Successfully
['script.py']` so i get ['script.py'], could you please tell me which Python Version are you using and did you check if the file was created or not.